# How to deserialize this dynamic valued JSON?

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit2

I want to deserialize the following JSON (in the original there are about 100 `Exchange`s with dynamic values):

```
{
  "Exchange1": {
    "EUR": [
      "CNY",
      "USD"
    ],
    "INR": [
      "USD",
      "CNY"
    ]
  },
  "Exchange2": {
    "BRL": [
      "EUR",
      "USD",
      "INR"
    ],
    "JPY": [
      "USD",
      "EUR",
      "CNY"
    ]
  },
  ....
}
```

I am using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ but it is generating a Java class taking literal values ("Exchange1", "EUR", etc) while I need to iterate this no matter what is the dynamic String value:

[image]

---

How can I describe this JSON with Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have POJOs here (in sane sense), but people tend to use POJO-generators that do not do ahead analysis even for dynamic objects.
"Dynamic" objects should be typically mapped using `java.util.Map` (ordered implementation) + unique values can be mapped using `java.util.Set` (ordered implementation).
Thus, if you have a custom enumeration for the currencies, say something like

```java
enum Currency {

    BRL,
    CNY,
    EUR,
    INR,
    JPY,
    USD,

}
```

then you can easily define the mapping without any POJOs that do not look applicable here at all:

```java
private static final Type exchangesType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<Currency, Set<Currency>>>>() {
}.getType();
```

```java
final Map<String, Map<Currency, Set<Currency>>> exchanges = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, exchangesType);
System.out.println(exchanges);
```

So the trivial `toString()` output will be as follows:

> {Exchange1={EUR=[CNY, USD], INR=[USD, CNY]}, Exchange2={BRL=[EUR, USD, INR], JPY=[USD, EUR, CNY]}}

If you don't like the idea of having the `Currency` enumeration (you must always keep it up to date with recompilation, etc), then you can simply declare the currency markers as `java.lang.String` and get the same result:

```
private static final Type exchangesType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>>>() {
}.getType();
```

```java
final Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> exchanges = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, exchangesType);
System.out.println(exchanges);
```

Comment: `Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>>` works perfectly for my case, thanks!